# Text output to a temporary file, compatible with Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, character-encoding, newline

I'd like to have a way to write Unicode text output to a temporary file created with `tempfile` API, which would support Python 3 style options for encoding and newline conversion, but would work also on Python 2.7 (for `unicode` values).

To open files with regular predictable names, a portable way is provided by `io.open`. But with temporary files, the secure way is to get an OS handle to the file, to ensure that the file name cannot be hijacked by a concurrent malicious process. There are no `io` workalikes to `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` or `os.fdopen`, and on Python 2.7 there are issues with the file objects obtained that way:

- the built-in file objects cannot be wrapped by `io.TextIoWrapper` which supports both encoding and newline conversion;
- the `codecs` API can produce an encoding writer, but that does not perform newline conversion. The underlying file must be opened in binary mode, otherwise the same code breaks in Python 3 (and it's generally not sane to expect correct newline conversion on arbitary character-encoded data).

I've come up with two ways to deal with the portability problem, each of which has certain disadvantages:

1. Close the file object (or the OS descriptor) without removing the file, and reopen the file by name with `io.open`. When using `NamedTemporaryFile`, this means the `delete` construction parameter has to be set to false and the user has the responsibility to delete the file when it's no longer needed. There is also an added security hazard, in the rather unusual case when the directory where temporary file is created is writable to potential attackers and the sticky bit is not set in its permission mode bits.
2. Write the entire output to an `io.StringIO` buffer created with `newline` parameter as appropriate, then write the buffered string into the encoding writer obtained from `codecs`. This is bad for performance and memory usage on large files.

Are there other alternatives?

Comment: Calling `close` on the file object/descriptor (without removing the file) and reopening the file with `io.open` is only slightly less secure than using the descriptor opened by `mkstemp`. In directories with the sticky bit in permissions, no other non-root process can hijack the file, and it's very unusual to create security-sensitive files in world-writable directories without the sticky bit. I will edit the question text to address that.